# How to add Custom large image to TabBar Controller bar item?

Tags: swift, uiimage, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have an image in the `tabBar`, which is larger than other icons,  but I can't see an image, I see only that image's frame.[image: How to change content mode]

Comment: my Image "Plus" is red round, i see only white frame of it

Comment: Add the code as well.

Comment: I have no code about it